# Finding a reduction formula for this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, recurrence-relations

Let $$I(n)=\int_0^1 (x-x^2)^n dx .$$
Mainly, what I'm trying to get is a recurrent form of this integral that probably involves 
$I(n-1)$.

My attempt  $(x-x^2)^n=(-(x^2-x+1/4-1/4))^n=(1/4-(x-1/2)^2)^n$. Let $t=x-\frac12$, hence the integral becomes

$$I(n)=\int_{1/2}^{3/2} \left(\frac14-t^2\right)^n dt .$$

Further , I tried integrating by parts , but I didn't manage to get anything .

Can someone try and find a reduction formula for this ?

Comment: $ x^2 - x = -(x^2 - x) = - ((x-1/2)^2 - 1/4) = 1/4 - (x-1/2)^2 $

Use substitution, $ y = x - 1/2 $ and $ y = 1/2 \cdot \sin \theta $, Wallis Product

Comment: $(x - x^2)^n = x^n(1 - x)^n$ should allow you to integrate by parts without any transformation.

Comment: @GohPiHan , oops , thanks a lot for spotting that stupid mistake :D

Comment: **If** you are not restricted to a recurrence that must only contain terms with $I(n)$, consider the beta function $B(p, q)=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1} dx}$ so $I(n)=B(n+1, n+1)$. You can easily show that $pB(p, q+1)=qB(p+1, q)$, so that $B(p, q)=\frac{(p-1)!(q-1)!}{(p+q-2)!}B(p+q-1, 1)=\frac{(p-1)!(q-1)!}{(p+q-1)!}$, so $I(n)=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$.

Comment: I'm a 12th grade student , I guess I'm restricted to a recurrence that implies I(n) directly . Sorry for not mentioning this , I had no clue that this problem can have such various approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}{x^n(1-x)^n dx}=-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1}(1-2x)'{x^n(1-x)^n dx}=-\frac{1}{2} (1-2x)x^n(1-x)^n|_0^1+$$$$+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}n(1-2x)^2{x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1} dx}=\frac{n}{2} \int_{0}^{1}[1-4(x-x^2)]{x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1} dx}=\frac{n}{2}I_{n-1}-2nI_n.$$
$$I_n=\frac{n}{2(2n+1)}I_{n-1}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Well... I guess if you are not allowed to use the beta function, you can do as follows:

\begin{align}
I(n)&=\int_{0}^{1}{x^n(1-x)^n dx} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}{x^n(1-x)^n(x+(1-x))^2 dx} \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n+2}(1-x)^n dx}+2\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1} dx}+\int_{0}^{1}{x^n(1-x)^{n+2} dx} \\
&=2I(n+1)+2\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n+2}(1-x)^n dx} \\
&=2I(n+1)+2\left(\left[-\frac{x^{n+2}(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]^1_0+\frac{n+2}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1} dx}\right) \\
&=2I(n+1)+2\frac{n+2}{n+1}I(n+1) \\
&=\frac{4n+6}{n+1}I(n+1)
\end{align}

where from the third to fourth line, we have used the change of variables $x \to 1-x$ for the third integral, and done integration by parts to get to the fifth line.

Comment: Very nice! I have a solution as elegant.

Answer (score 1):

With Tunococ's suggestion, we can apply [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).