# How to arrive at this integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, summation

Quoted from: [Finding a reduction formula for this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803307/finding-a-reduction-formula-for-this-integral?rq=1).

However, I am not sure how to arrive at this:
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{=}&\color{green}{\int_0^1x^{n+2}(1-x)^n\,dx}+2\int_0^1x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1}\,dx+\color{green}{\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^{n+2}\,dx}\\
=&2I(n+1)+\color{green}{2\int_0^1x^{n+2}(1-x)^n\,dx}
\end{align}$$

and why the highlighted part is equal to each other? What type of integral is that?

Comment: Symmetry about $x=\frac12$

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Exchange! I have edited your question for you but in the future please use Mathjax (similar to LaTeX) to write any questions as it is more accessible for other users. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, if symmetry is no the first thing you saw:

$$\int_0^1x^{n+2}(1-x)^ndx = \left[\begin{align}
t &=1-x
\\-dt &=dx
\\ x &=0,1\leftrightarrow t=1,0
\\x &=1-t\end{align}
\right]=\int_0^1(1-t)^{n+2}t^ndt=\int_0^1(1-x)^{n+2}x^ndx$$